# Is there a Bitcoin casino that is willing to collaborate on some economics research?

Tags: economic-theory, gambling, user-data

Am looking to collaborate with the owners of some of the online Bitcoin casinos. I am in the process of designing some behavioural experiments to test for biases in Bitcoin gamblers.

I will sign NDA agreements with whoever wants to talk to me about them and am also happy to go through a fiduciary to anonymise which site the data comes from.

Thanks

Jonathan

Comment: You might want to reach-out to Bitcoin casinos with your request then, perhaps post this on reddit.com/r/bitcoin or bitcointalk.org. (Voted to close, not a question.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a question, but rather a contact request.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of gambling games are completely on-chain, you can analyze the blockchain and look for these transactions to get the data you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt that this is a right place to ask such questions. In my opinion the best way is to contact Bitcoin casinos through feedback form on the site. Keep in mind that most probably they would be reluctant in accepting your offer, because I highly doubt that it would be useful for them, but some of their customers might be disappointed with this move.

One additional plus might be if you are an established scientist (for working for established institution), in which case you might be able to generate some fuss and therefore create some advertisement through your research.